# AssertionError on totally unrelated line of code - Junit test for school project

Tags: java, junit, rmi, assertions

I am working on a Java RMI project and I am trying to begin to test the code I've written and when I run the following code, I get an AssertionError on a line that doesn't even have an assertion statement. I am confused as to how to fix this.

```
public void basicTest() throws UnknownHostException, RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException, NotBoundException, InterruptedException {
        int numBooks = 20;
        int copiesPerBook = 5;
        int booksPerMember = 4;

        // Simulate the server
        LibraryServerImpl library = new LibraryServerImpl(numBooks, copiesPerBook, booksPerMember);
        LibraryServer stub = (LibraryServer) java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(library, 0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        registry.bind(libraryName, stub);

        // Simulate the client
        Member member = new MemberImpl();
        assertNotNull(member.getName()); // Will fail until you implement MemberImpl
        Thread t = new Thread(new BasicClient(member));
        t.start();
        t.join();
    }
```

This is the copied trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:712)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:722)
    at PublicTests.basicTest(PublicTests.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Line 56 corresponds to registry.bind(libraryName, stub);

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't point to `assertNotNull(member.getName());`? Refresh your project, rebuild and rerun. Breakpoints can stay fixed on lines if you edit the code around them they don't move with it sometimes. Other than that try putting `assert registry != null` and ensuring the parameters are also not null with more asserts or `if (blah != null) {..}` blocks to make sure that nothing you want to use is null where it shouldn't be.

Comment: There is a LibraryServerImpl class which is an implementation of the LibraryServer remote class, and MemberImpl which is an implementation of the Member remote class. These both have main methods with nothing in it. Would this potentially cause a problem, since neither main method (server or client) have anything in their main method. Despite this, I dont feel like it should say assertionError when it should still be creating a LIbraryServer object

Comment: It's possible that the constructors or methods of those library objects (are they 3rd party or do you have access to modify them?) are throwing the AssertionErrors. You could debug that section of code and step into all the involved methods to pinpoint exactly where and why the Exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, this does not make sense, so one of the facts is false.

Fact: you got the above stack trace. --no reason to doubt the truthfulness of this fact.

Fact: PublicTests.java is written by you. --no reason to doubt the truthfulness of this fact.

Fact: line 56 of PublicTests.java corresponds to `registry.bind(libraryName, stub)`.  Well, this cannot be true, since according to the stack trace, the failure is detected by a call to `org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull()`, but the line `registry.bind(libraryName, stub)` is *not* an invocation of `org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull()`.

However, further down in your code you do have an invocation of `assertNotNull(member.getName())`, which means that this must be what is being reported as line 56.

So, what you are looking at is a mismatch in the line number being reported in the stack trace.  As user `indivisible` suggested, please refresh your project, clean your output folder, rebuild all projects, and try again.

Comment: I bet he's using Eclipse

Comment: Yup, it smells of Eclipse.  No, it stinks of it.  I really do not know why anyone bothers with it when there exist such awesome (and equally free) alternatives such as IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.  Eclipse kills my inner child.